# Capture key or mouse press with inactive terminal window to end program

Tags: python, linux, mouseevent, keypress

I am trying to automate some cookie-clicker style game (on a website) by letting python click my mouse for me on an ubuntu system. The clicking part is functioning fine, but I cant seem to cancel my program with CTRL-C because the browser window is active since I am constantly clicking on it with a moving mouse. For now I have a timed solution, but thats not really optimal.

Here is my very simple code:

```
from pymouse import PyMouse
from pymouse import PyMouseEvent
import time
from datetime import datetime

m = PyMouse()

x,y = m.position() #gets mouse current position coordinates

print x
print y

finish = datetime(2016, 3, 21, 14, 1)
print finish

while datetime.now() < finish:
    for y in range(160,520,3):  
        time.sleep(0.005)
        m.click(470,y,1)
```

I looked at the PyMouse examples and found a part to end my program by right-clicking, but I cant seem to get it working if I try to combine this.

```
from pymouse import PyMouse
from pymouse import PyMouseEvent
import time
from datetime import datetime


class Clickonacci(PyMouseEvent):

    def cookies(self):
        m = PyMouse()

        x,y = m.position() #gets mouse current position coordinates

        print x
        print y

        finish = datetime(2016, 3, 21, 14, 41)
        print finish

        while datetime.now() < finish:      
            for y in range(160,520,3):  
                time.sleep(0.005)
                m.click(470,y,1)


    def __init__(self):
        PyMouseEvent.__init__(self)
        self.cookies()

    def click(self, x, y, button, press):
        if button == 2:
            if press:
                self.stop()

C = Clickonacci()
C.run()
```

This lets me exit my program by right-clicking and prints the initial mouse coordinates, but its not controlling the mouse to click automated on the given positions.

Maybe anyone with more experience can untangle this to make it work?

EDIT:

I installed via pip install pymouse, not sure if its the same version as https://github.com/pepijndevos/PyMouse

So I am searching for a way to end my program either by right-clicking my mouse or pressing a certain key even when the terminal window in which I started my program is not the active window.